# what is the meaning of query *:value in lucene?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

What is the meaning of this query in lucene ?

```
Query query =new QueryParser(Version.LATEST,"*",analyzer).parse("value");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a QueryParser for the field "*" (I'm not sure if actual wildcards are allowed here - try!), using the specified analyzer. It then parses the textual query ("value") for that field. This returns a Query, which you can then use for searching through `searcher.Search(query);`.

Comment: but the MatchAllDocQuery is converted to *:* but  match all the fields